# Strpos() array trouble

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add some text each of an array element. But also I want add that text specific array elements. That's why I used strpos, but this error popped up. `Strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Here are my codes:

```
$outline = 'outline/index.html';
$allDivs = [];
$allDivs = $parser->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($allDivs as $div) {
    if ($div->getAttribute('class') == 'p-articlelist-content-right') {
        if ($div != null) {
            $links = $div->getElementsByTagName('a');
            if ($links->length > 0) {
                $a = $links->item(0);
                $link[] = $a->getAttribute('href');
            } if(strpos($link, 'https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp') === 0) {
                foreach($link as $value) {

                    var_dump($value . $outline);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what am I missing here? Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: The error contains your answer. You have `$link[]` array. Try just `$link` if `getAttribute('href')` returns a string and use that. And you also have the if statement with `strpos` usage outside of the definition of the `$link` attribute, so this won't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strpos` operates on strings, `$link` is an array, as the error states.
I *think* that this is what you want:

```
if ($links->length > 0) {
  $a = $links->item(0);
  $linkRef = $a->getAttribute('href');
  if (strpos($linkRef, 'https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp') === 0) {
    // This will only work for urls that end on '/' but fail for example.com/index.html
    $linkRef .= $outline;
  }
  $link[] = $linkRef;
}
```

Comment: mate, it says `Undefined variable: link`